# Xamarin IOS And Parse can't update existing object

Tags: xamarin, parse-platform

I am trying to use parse.com with xamarin ios but I can't seem to figure out how. It should but it doesn't seem to like the public call. Is there another way to retrieve and update an object in xamarin ios?

```
// Retrieve the object by id
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("UserName");
query.getInBackground("tJLv7tTacZ", new GetCallback() {
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            object.put("Name", username);
            object.saveInBackground();
        } else {
            // do something with the error...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or exception?  What exactly is the problem?  You haven't really asked a specific question.  Are you using one of the many available tutorials on Parse and Xamarin?

Comment: @Jason yes i dont no why but when i place the code in a existing method it brakes i was wanting to have a method like sendmessage (int id,string message) but it then complains about the public and says unexpected symbol public

Answer (score 0):

try using new `GetCallback<ParseObject>()`

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyClass");
 query.getInBackground(myId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
     public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
             objectWasRetrievedSuccessfully(object);
         } else {
             objectRetrievalFailed();
         }
     }
 }
```